# JPA incorrect merge before or after loop

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

my function is st like this:

```
@Transactional
void changeData(CardTO cardTO){
       List<CardTO> sameParentCards = cardFactory.getSameParentCards(cardTO.getParentId());

    cardTO.setArchived(true);
    entityManager.merge(cardTO);

    for(CardTO c: sameParentCards )
    {
       if(!c.getCardId.equals(cardTO.getCardId()))
       {
           c.setParentId(cardTO.getParentId());
           entityManager.merge(c);
           break;
       }
    } 
    }
```

in which "getSameCards" method returns list of cardTO whit parent id equal to given card id.
The result of this function doesn't save "Archived" field in db but inside loop everything is correctly saved. merging after loop also results the same! where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not retrieving entity after saving them inside one transnational function. So I retrieved cardTO after merging data like this:

```
cardTO.setArchived(true);
entityManager.merge(cardTO);
cardTO = cardFactory.getCardTO(cardTO.getId());
```